# How to pause clients certificate activity for OpenVPN?

Tags: openvpn, certificate, pause

I use OpenVPN and also I want to pause activity of some client certificates, and after some time to start it again (without new certificate generation). So how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably just remove their entry from index.txt and then add it back afterwards.  I don't know if index.txt supports any sort of comment syntax.  If it does, you could just comment it out temporarily.